# Autocomplete for address using Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps

I came across a challenge and I kindly needed your help. I was developing form input with one of the fields being address / location. I wanted to harness Google Maps API, with services such as AutoComplete and Address Geocoding. I have HTML and JS files. My main issue is that I wanted to tap invalid addresses that users might type and alert them that it is an error. Like for instance, if someone types an address that has not been suggested or types incomplete address, I should be able to tell them that it is not a valid address. This works but only when I press enter, and not submit. If I press submit, it submits the form and doesn't notify.

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places">
function initMap() {
    const input = document.getElementById("location-input");
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (!place.geometry) {
          // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
          // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
          //window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
          swal("Please fill all the *Required fields","Click okay to continue", "warning");
          return;
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Franklin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script> -->
    
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="mform">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!--Address Section-->
                <div id="pac-container">
                    <input id="location-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" />
                  </div>
                <!--End of Address Section-->
                <!--Form Submit Section-->
                <div class="row fill-form">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
                <!--End of Form Submit Section-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="places.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding an submit event listener, but I cannot get what I expect

Comment: Well you would need some kind of validation before submitting the form. For example, disable the submit button until you have a valid address (`place.geometry`), disable it again if the address is changed again to something that doesn't "exist" (exist as in the API). You have different approaches. It depends on how "safe" it must be.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Pressing the Enter key returns the alert, but the submit button soesn.t, it submits the address whether valid or not. Is there a way I can maybe say if (place.geometry) is valid, submit form, else return error. I have tried many possible ways around it, I am still not successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first prevent the form from submitting and check `place.geometry` the way you check it on `place_changed` event. Show that nice `swal` message and then do whatever you want to if it's valid.

Here below is your own codes edited and checked before submit.

```
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places">
function initMap() {
  const input = document.getElementById("location-input");
  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
  
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      //window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      swal("Please fill all the *Required fields","Click okay to continue", "warning");
      return;
    }
  });

  //Check before submit
  document.getElementById('mform').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace(); //get place from autocomplete
    if (!place.geometry) { //check if valid location
      swal("Please fill all the *Required fields","Click okay to continue", "warning");
      return;
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: Finally it now works! Thanks Remon, Nice time buddy!

Comment: Most welcome @Steel8. I made a silly mistake just check like this `if (!place || !place.geometry)` instead `if (!place.geometry)`, otherwise it will cause error on first time.

Comment: But the console did not show any errors at all, let me change that

Comment: Oooh and one more thing, can I call more than one function when i listen to an event? Because the same input has to be geocoded and saved to a database as coordinates, and i have another function to geocode, now when i submit, it doesn't show the alert if I type an address not found in the Google Maps Suggestion panel

Comment: This will make 2 API calls instead of 1. Not very efficient.

Comment: Okay now how will I go about it, is there a way possible that can help me solve it.

Comment: @FoysalRemon Hey Remon, I came across another problem, I know you good in this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697958/google-places-autocomplete-geocoding-and-address-validation). Help me inspect this, I will appreciate